# Multi-character character constant error in strchr()

Tags: c, cs50

I'm working on a CS50 problem set. In this function I'm iterating over a line to make sure it is consistent with certain rules: "method SP request-target SP HTTP-version CRLF" where SP is space, CRLF is carriage return/new line.

I go through the last part of the string to find CRLF to confirm it's there in the following way:

```
//needle2 is a subset of the line, here it's the last bit: "HTTP-version CRLF"   
const char* needle3 = strchr(needle2, '\r\n'); 
if (needle3 == NULL)
{
    error(400);
    return false;
}
```

I get an error message when compiling this code: error:

```
error: multi-character character constant [-Werror,-Wmultichar] 
const char* needle3 = strchr(needle2, '\r\n');
```

I understand that I'm looking for multiple characters in a function that should take in only 1 character at a time. 
But how can I look for CRLF to make sure it's there without having the multi-character error?

I tried using strstr() function in the exact same way the distribution code uses it, and I get an error, which is even more confusing since I use code that is working within the same program.

Comment: Use `strstr` with `"\r\n"` There is not multi-character constant; that is called a string.

Comment: kooky approach using _"multi-character constant"_ instead of _"string literal constant"_

Comment: @PaulOgilvie, I tried with strstr() and I get an error 'incompatible pointer to integer comparison'.
EDIT: now that I think about it, I might have messed up the syntax... I'll recheck!

Comment: Search for `\r` then check that `\n` is right next to it.

Answer (score 0):

As Paul Ogilvie suggests:

```
//needle2 is a subset of the line, here it's the last bit: "HTTP-version CRLF"   
const char* needle3 = strstr(needle2, "\r\n"); 
if (needle3 == NULL)
{
    error(400);
    return false;
}
```